# Drag Drop on ASP.Net Tree View

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to implement the drag drop functionality on ASP.Net tree view. In my tree view the file and folder is showing.

I want user select a file from his computer and drag drop to ASP.Net Tree and file will upload on the server.

Is this possible in ASP.Net Tree View?

Answer (score 0):

You can try witj `JsTree`

Link : http://www.jstree.com/